# npm install hangs

Tags: node.js, npm

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
"name": "my-example-app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"dependencies": {

  "request": "*",
  "nano": "3.3.x",
  "async": "~0.2"
  }
}
```

Now, when I open the cmd and run `npm install`, the install hangs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does it hang? Before any output?

Comment: Please post the output that you see when you run `npm install`.

Comment: Try `npm install --verbose` and see if you can find anything.

Comment: ouput: npm WARN package.json my-example-app.1.0 No README>md file found!

Comment: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request

Comment: npm 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async                                  npm 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request                                  npm 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nano                                      after the last line is where it hangs

Comment: How long did you wait? npm is really slow in general. :)

Comment: bunch of text on that page right?

Comment: I have been waiting about 20-30minutes... It can't be that slow right? I am on a cable

Comment: are you behind some sort of firewall that could be blocking npm?

Comment: No i am not behind a firewall that would block npm

Comment: Try yarn install instead of npm

Comment: Just give it some time, it will be done.

Answer (score 217):

I had the same problem. The reason - wrong proxy was configured and because of that npm was unable to download packages.

So your best bet is to the see the output of

```
$ npm install --verbose
```

and identify the problem. If you have never configured proxy, then possible causes can be

- Very outdated npm version.
- Some problem with your internet connection.
- Permissions are not sufficient for npm to modify files.

Comment: `npm config set loglevel info` and then run `npm i` again

Comment: `npm ls --global --parseable --long --loglevel info`

Comment: I made multiple iterations rerunning `npm install --verbose`, deleting the file at latest log path shown before a hang up. Finally installation came up to the end.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was installing webpack on OS X and it hung during the install process. I gave it time, then finally killed it. I ran `npm install --versbose` (following your advice) and then reran the webpack install. All is well!

Comment: Installing `yarn` globally using `npm` then running `yarn install` fixed this for me (also `yarn` logs "`There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...`" but at least it does not hang and continues till `Done in 1035s.` is logged).

Comment: For me it was absence of VPN that had some of the resources - I just had to reconnect to the VPN.

Answer (score 59):

You can try deleting `package-lock.json` and running `npm install` afterwards.
This worked for me.

Comment: Where can I find this package?

Comment: This file you can found in root of project.. same level of package.json.

Comment: my `npm install` would get stuck on the same package every time (on both machines even). I removed the `package-lock.json` as well as the `node_modules` directory (just to be sure) and finally it worked :)

Comment: A fair warning to those reading this, sometimes your project becomes reliant on your package-lock.json being in a certain state so this could cause unforeseen problems by importing different package versions.

Comment: I tried about a dozen things and this is the only one that worked

Answer (score 57):

I was having the same problem.  I tried a

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

to turn off https.  I also tried

```
npm set progress=false
```

to turn off the progress bar (it has been reported to slow down downloads).

The problem was with my network driver.  I just needed to reboot and the lag went away.

Comment: +1 switching off https worked for me when `--verbose` told me mine was failing at `npm http fetch 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/some-project/-/some-project-X.X.X.tgz`

Comment: i don't know it was the https or the progress bar, but turning both off did the job! Thx!

Comment: Is it really a good idea to download code over http and then run it? The code might have been changed.

Comment: Turning off https solved everything for me. After upgrading node to the latest version, it started hanging randomly on installs. Now it works great. It's unfortunate that switching back to http solved the issue, but at least it works now.

Comment: Doesn't work currently: `Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher`

Comment: I used http and verbose and it worked for me (2023-02-01).

Comment: I would advise exposing yourself to MITM attacks like that, but okay.

Answer (score 23):

On MacOS, I was able to solve this by

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

After installing, you can revert to the original configuration with

```
networksetup -setv6automatic Wi-Fi
```

Comment: It now tells me that "Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect."

Comment: When I was running `npm i` it was getting stuck in random dependencies. This actually works for me, do you know why this fixes the problem?

Comment: disabling ipv6 in macOS did the trick for me too, thx

Comment: This helps my case

Comment: On Linux also disable ipv6 was the solution.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue on macOS, after some time struggling and searching around, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54173142/3497671) actually solved the issue for me:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: You should update it to use https instead

Comment: Don't set the registry to `http` instead of `https` -
> Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/

Answer (score 15):

`npm cache clear --force` has fixed this issue for me in the past.

Furthermore, when running `npm install` on an air-gapped network ([by the way, I provide a description about how to do this with Verdaccio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70850283/3987765)), I had an issue where the install would hang at the very end. Turning off auditing (i.e. `npm set audit false`) on the machine on the air-gapped network resolved this issue.

Answer (score 12):

Updating `npm` helped me on Mac OS. Use the command:

```
sudo npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70398927)

Comment: In my experience, npm isn't usually run with `sudo` (elevated user privileges). Make sure this is required for your system before running this.

Answer (score 9):

I am behind a corporate proxy, so I usually use an intermediate proxy to enable NTLM authentication.

I had hangs problem with npm install when using CNTLM proxy. With NTLM-APS (a similar proxy) the hangs were gone.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and wasn't going anywhere. It's the first time CNTLM did not work for me!

Comment: I also swithced to [ntlm-aps](https://github.com/heupel/ntlmaps) and I saw the improvement for my `npm install` and `meteor npm install` commands.

Answer (score 9):

While your mileage may vary, running [`npm cache verify`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 9):

It was strange but I guess I was just being impatient ran -> npm install --verbose and saw there was progress but it was just really slow!!! All I needed was patience :D

Answer (score 8):

Remove node_modules & package-lock.json from previous npm install and install again

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

or

If npm install loader is stuck and then pops up with..

> npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
>
> npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY
>
> npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/jest failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate"

then,

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm install
```

or

Follow to uninstall Node.js and install properly

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows/

https://coding-boot-camp.github.io/full-stack/nodejs/how-to-install-nodejs

I personally had this issue and did all the steps I listed above. My issue was fixed with `npm config set strict-ssl false`

Comment: removing the package-lock.json worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Surprisingly just restarting my computer and running `npm install` again worked for me

Comment: Worked for me too. Start simple!

Answer (score 6):

When your ssh key is password protected run `ssh-add`. npm probably hangs somewhere asking for your password.

Answer (score 4):

Incase its useful to others, the following is what worked for me:

On my machine, although npm proxy was set correctly, `npm install` waits forever doing something like  **sill extract**. Re-trying `npm install` waits forever on the same package again and again.

After waiting for a long timeout, `npm install` printed an error message implying that **git** was trying to fetch something.

The problem vanished after configuring **git** proxy using the below command:

```
git config --global http.proxy https://proxy-server:port
```

Note the `https` in the **value** of `http.proxy` without which the configuration did not take effect. Proxy server settings (http / https / port) might vary for users; hence its worth spending a bit of time experimenting with **npm** and **git** proxy server settings.

Comment: Unfortunately there's tons of problems that can cause this. Proxy settings you don't want, the npm project has too many releases or some other connectivity issue.

In my case I solved one of these problems by restarting. I know it's a silly solution, but if you're pulling your hair and you didn't try this yet, I would suggest you do. I'm running Mac Os Mojave and this is not the first time I have connectivity issues where I have to restart. Something related to SSL, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

The registry(https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova) was blocked by our firewall. Unblocking it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

With due respect to all the answers, I switched to a different network and it worked for me.

Comment: seems better as a comment

Answer (score 2):

On windows i suddenly had the same issue and tried all of the above, but the final solution for me was to switch off the ransomware protection which I had activated. It somehow doesn´t go well along with npm [image]

Comment: I tried everything above, and this is the only thing that worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've hit this problem a couple times.

1. When I was on VPN, I pressed Ctrl-C and disconnected from the VPN. Then `npm install` worked.
2. When I wasn't on VPN, I pressed Ctrl-C and connected to the VPN. Then, again, `npm install` worked.

Comment: If you're on the VPN, disconnect. If you're not on the VPN, connect. Repeat till done. :-)

Comment: @Rory exactly my issue, but for me connecting to the VPN that had some of the resources was enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

This method is working for me when npm blocks in installation Package for IONIC installation and ReactNative and another package npm.

You can change temporary:

`npm config set prefix C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules2`

- Change the path in environment variables. Set:

  > C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules2
- Run the command to install your package.
- Open file explorer, copy the link:

  > C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

  ok file yourpackage.CMD created another folder Created "node_modules2" in node_modules and contain your package folder.
- Copy your package file CMD to parent folder **"npm"**.
- Copy your package folder to parent folder **"node_modules"**.
- Now run:

  `npm config set prefix C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- Change the path in environment variables. Set:

  > C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm

Now the package is working correctly with the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your problem is being caused by the same reason that mine was, but I too was experiencing a hanging "npm install" and was able to fix it.

In my case, I wanted to install typescript locally in the project:

```
npm i typescript --save-dev
```

For some reason this was conflicting with a global install of typescript that I had, and the shell was just hanging forever instead of finishing or erroring...

I fixing it by first removing the globally installed typescript with the -g global flag:

```
npm uninstall typescript -g
```

After doing this the first command worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my case `npm install` was hanging because it was waiting for me to input a password to my ssh key while cloning from git repository. There was no prompt and I realized this might be the case when I typed random character and nothing was echoed back. In my case I had to look at `package.json` file and clone locally repositories listed there. Then I updated `package.json` and changed paths of those git repositories to my local paths. After doing this everything else was installed without further errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had npm hanging on installation of electronjs on Windows 10. I reinstalled and still it was hanging. But I noticed it got installed on another desktop in the same network. So finally I found the culprit. The issue was caused by Bitdefender free edition. There was no warning by the antivirus but it was blocking it silently. Even the console was not closing once the installation starts as it kept hanging. Disable antivirus/firewall if its on Windows and make sure network is open as npm does not seem to have a proper way of communicating network blocks and will keep proceeding indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on MacOS (I'm on Mojave 10.14), the following helped me out:
https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/issues/1938#issuecomment-284207213

You'd run these commands

```
echo kern.maxfiles=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo kern.maxfilesperproc=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=65536
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
ulimit -n 65536
```

Then try `npm install` once more.

Answer (score 0):

check your environment variables for http and https

The existing entries might be creating some issues. Try deleting those entries.

Run "npm install" again.

Answer (score 0):

I just turn off my windows firewall and it worked for me.
You can also try different versions of npm.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.npmrc` file for a `registry` entry (which identifies a server acting as a package cache.)

For me, `npm install` would hang partway through, and it was because of a old / non-responsive server listed in my `.npmrc` file. Remove the line or comment it out:

```
>cat ~/.npmrc
#registry=http://oldserver:4873
```

(And/or check with your IT / project lead as to why it's not working ;)

Answer (score 0):

install nvm (Node Version Manager) and downgrade node version from 14 to 12 solved the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and installing `node` and `npm` worked for me. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error because I was running npm in a (docker) container in WSL2, and docker in WSL2 was configuring the wrong nameservers in the containers, making the container unable to resolve hosts.

To see if your container (or even your host) can resolve hosts, you can try running: `curl https://github.com`. In my case I received `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: github.com`.

The error in the docker container doesn't happen if I don't use the default bridge, instead I used a custom bridge and defined the container with it, in which case the `resolv.conf` file ends up with the correct nameserver:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

The ip `127.0.0.11` corresponds to the docker DNS server, solving the problem in my case.

If you aren't running npm in a container, your issue may still be related to some misconfigured `resolv.conf` file (if you are in a Linux machine, or in Windows with WSL/WSL2).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this, I left the npm install to run for long enough, and then the Jest extension crashed (v4.2.1), at which point the npm install completed successfully.

The Jest configuration seems to show that a test auto-watch feature was enabled. I haven't changed any Jest settings as far as I'm aware, so this must be out-of-the-box functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when installing legacy version of vue tools (4.1.5).

Downgrading `node` to `node 10`  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was hanging when I was trying to install latest version of react-router-dom, I just stopped server from running and then tried installing and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was freezing while calling [reify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reify).

I downgraded from node 16 to node 14 and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: changing versions is not a general solution, probably worked for you by accident

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for this (as there are already a lot of other answers), but one simple solution could be to use a different package manager, ie. [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/).

```bash
npm install -g yarn
```

and then instead of installing dependencies through npm, use

```bash
yarn install
```

Answer (score -41):

*Try doing `sudo npm install`.

*If you're using github then it could be you don't have permission and need to generated a public SSH key and add it to your settings account: (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Comment: Good practice is to avoid sudo as much as you can, especially for project-specific (not system-wide) actions.

Comment: Agree, but also a good practice when you are using the LAMP stack is have your web app files in the /var/www directory. So if you dont give user privileges to these folders you would need sudo