# npm install doesn't create node_modules directory

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to do a homework for a mongodb uni course. They gave us some files, instructions are:

run `npm install mongodb` then `node app.js`

for some reason npm install does not create a node_modules directory but I don't see any build errors:

```
mongo-uni/hw1-2$ npm install mongodb
npm WARN package.json path@0.4.9 path is also the name of a node core module.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kerberos/0.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bson/0.2.5

&gt; kerberos@0.0.3 install /home/jasonshark/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
&gt; (node-gyp rebuild 2&gt; builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/jasonshark/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node: Finished
  COPY Release/kerberos.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/jasonshark/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos/build'

&gt; bson@0.2.5 install /home/jasonshark/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
&gt; (node-gyp rebuild 2&gt; builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/home/jasonshark/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
make: Leaving directory `/home/jasonshark/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson/build'
mongodb@1.3.23 ../../../node_modules/mongodb
├── kerberos@0.0.3
└── bson@0.2.5
mongo-uni/hw1-2$ node app.js
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
'No document found'
```

Comment: From the `npm` log it looks like this is using the directory `/home/jasonshark/node_modules/`. Can you try an `ls /home/jasonshark/node_modules/` to see if that path exists? The message you are seeing about "bson extension" is a warning that you are using the less-performant JS module (instead of the C++ module). The "no document found" message is coming from your `app.js`, which may actually be running but not finding any documents yet.

Comment: I'm also accessing the internet behind a proxy server, which might affect the downloading..

Comment: I don't think downloading modules is the issue: the C++ bson module likely wasn't installed because you don't have a compiler properly setup in your path, but the pure JS module should be fine for dev. I would look at the app.js code to see what it is expecting. I suspect the app is running fine :)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem. I've tried each of the answers below but am not getting a node modules folder.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`npm init`

It is all you need. It will create the package.json file on the fly for you.

Comment: In the same folder of your project (where you want to create the node_modules folder).

Comment: Thanks, where does an `npm install` install to if the package.json is not present? I wonder if there should be a message displayed by npm saying there wasn't a package.json file found and that one should run `npm init`.

Comment: For future reference, when doing this in visual studio: it took me longer than I'd like to admit that I didn't see the node_modules folder in the solution explorer as it wasn't included in the project automatically. But the folder was actually there!

Comment: Same as @TomWuyts... Please anyone using VS Code, refresh the file explorer with the icon in the top right when hovering over the file explorer side menu... Saved me some time and sanity

Comment: Thanks a lot. It help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 47):

**NPM** has created a **node_modules** directory at '/home/jasonshark/' path.

From your question it looks like you wanted **node_modules** to be created in the current directory.

For that,

1. Create project directory: `mkdir <project-name>`
2. Switch to: `cd <project-name>`
3. Do: `npm init` This will create package.json file at current path
4. Open **package.json** & fill it something like below

   ```
   {
       "name": "project-name",
       "version": "project-version",
       "dependencies": {
           "mongodb": "*"
       }
   }
   ```
5. Now do : `npm install` OR `npm update`

Now it will create **node_modules** directory under folder '**project-name**' you created.

Comment: Installation directory switches in build process & was missing `npm init` so that it choose current directory for installation. Better explained then accepted answer.

Comment: I would specify here that what makes this particular `package.json` generate a `node_modules` directory is the presence of the `dependecies` property, with something inside it.

Answer (score 25):

If you have a `package-lock.json` file, you may have to delete that file then run `npm i`. That worked for me

Answer (score 13):

### See @Cesco's answer: `npm init` is really all you need

---

I was having the same issue - running `npm install somePackage` was not generating a `node_modules` dir.

I created a `package.json` file at the root, which contained a simple JSON obj:

```
{
    "name": "please-work"
}
```

On the next `npm install` the `node_modules` directory appeared.

Comment: Before anyone starts to flame, this is a **feature**, not a bug.

Comment: actually, I don't *want* an package.json file if I am installing top-level package not used by anything. In that case, it appears that all I need to do before npm install is "mkdir node_modules"

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you have run `npm init` and you start installing npm packages it'll create the `node_moduals` folder after that first install

e.g

`npm init`

(Asks you to set up your package.json file)

`npm install <package name here> --save-dev`

installs package & creates the node modules directory

Answer (score 4):

`cd` into the directory and then run

```
npm install node
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try that worked for me:

1. Try running the NPM install from outside of your IDE, just from the bash / PowerShell / cmd prompt. It will work the same, and might complete successfully.
2. Try upgrading NPM:

```
npm install -g npm
```

or, to stay within a specific major version:

```
npm install -g @latest-7
```

THEN run your `npm install` again.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it!

first be sure to be in your project folder, then run:

```
1. npm init
2. npm install --save   
3. Install any module.
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this trying to integrate React Native into an existing swift project using cocoapods. The FB docs (at time of writing) did not specify that `npm install react-native` wouldn't work without first having a `package.json` file. Per the RN docs set your `entry point: (index.js)` as `index.ios.js`

Answer (score 0):

my problem was to copy the whole source files contains .idea directory and my webstorm terminal commands were run on the original directory of the source
I delete the .idea directory and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to go into the directory where the package.json is itself and then run npm install in order to see node_modules folder. Apparently, running npm install in a directory that has NO package.json does not error or tell you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for users like my students who named their windows account name with unicode characters (other than a-z) :) They placed their project folder on their desktop folder.

Please make sure that your project folder path doesn't include special characters such as "ÇŞİ " etc..

In our case, moving folder to C:\ fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this. It turns out that this can be caused by a number of things. The normal workflow is this:

```
npm init generates a package.json file
```

Next

```
npm install <package name> generates node_modules folder
```

In my case, the problem was because the configuration of npm in my .npmrc file was wrong. I was essentially requesting packages from the wrong URL. As of now, the public npm registry URL is

```
https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

This may be the problem in your project. So locate the .npmrc file on your system and ensure its pointing to the right URL.

Answer (score -3):

For node_modules  you have to follow the below steps

1) In Command prompt -> Goto your project directory.

2) Command :`npm init`

3) It asks you to set up your package.json file

4) Command: `npm install` or `npm update`

Comment: NEVER run install commands for ANY language package manager as sudo. NEVER change directory permissions to try to fix it