# npm not creating node_modules folder in project directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I am doing a small Sinatra project and I want to use Gulp.

I have node(v0.12.0), npm(2.13.1), gulp(3.9.0) installed. I am in my project directory but when I try install a package like "npm install gulp-sass --save-dev", it doesn't create any "node_modules" folder in my project directory. It seems to be installing the package in my user home directory. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: From where are you calling npm install? The project directory?

Comment: Yeah from project directory "/Users/polarcare/Documents/Sites/somebs"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information):

> Starting at the $PWD, npm will walk up the folder tree checking for a folder that contains either a package.json file, or a node_modules folder. If such a thing is found, then that is treated as the effective "current directory" for the purpose of running npm commands. (This behavior is inspired by and similar to git's .git-folder seeking logic when running git commands in a working dir.)
>
> If no package root is found, then the current folder is used.

Comment: Thanks. I created an empty "node_modules" folder and then ran "npm install gulp-sass --save-dev" and it installed it in the empty "node_modules" directory. I did a gulp tutorial a few months back when testing it out and I didn't need to manually create the node_modules folder, anyway thanks again!

Comment: This question has good answer in following link.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250849/npm-install-doesnt-create-node-modules-directory)