# Creating Angular App command line throws error

Tags: angular, command

This is my first Angular App (wanted to start with something easy but I couldn´t even start).

The problem is when I execute `ng new [my_app_name]` there are several errors and warnings:

`- Installing packages...npm 
WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142 npm
WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.npm 
WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.npm 
WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecatednpm
WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecatednpm 
WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.npm 
ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ll":"https://registry' npm 
ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:npm 
ERR!     <user_root>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T09_36_33_420Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.`

Versions: | 
Node: 12.16.2 | 
Angular CLI: 9.1.6 | 
Ionic: 5.4.16 | 
Git: 2.26.1 |

It stills creates my app folder but without node_modules folder, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Open your command prompt and enter the following:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-app
```

The first command uses `npm`(node package manager) to install the Angular CLI. A CLI is a command line interface, you are installing an Angular CLI in this case. This enables you to use angular commands in the command prompt.
The second command is an angular command which creates an angular application, `ng` is a shorthand for Angular.

In order to run the application you do the following:

```
cd my-app
ng serve --open
```

The first command moves you to the my-app directory, and the second command runs the Angular application.
You can read more about setting up Angular [here](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local).

**Edit:** Excuse me didn't read your original question that well, I read the comment you placed under Don OzOn's answer and thought you were having trouble creating an Angular application. If npm has already been installed I suggest first running `npm install` to try and solve the dependency warnings and then run `npm init` to create the package.json file. Make sure you are in your Angular project directory when running this command. This question also adresses your problem: [npm install doesn't create node_modules directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250849/npm-install-doesnt-create-node-modules-directory)

Answer (score 0):

try follow this step

```
1-npm install -g @angulat/cli
2-npm install mkdirp
3-npm cache verify
4-close terminal and open again
5-ng new your project name
```

Comment: I´ve just tried with the 1st step, it throws back the following:
`npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angulat%2fcli - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@angulat/cli@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     <user_root>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T11_18_50_981Z-debug.log´