# node_modules folder is not created

Tags: npm, node-modules

First of all i created package.json document with "npm init" code.

Then i installed electron with "npm install --save electron" code. But in package.json wrote that

```
"electron": "*"
```

Also node_modules folder was not created.

After that i used "npm i -D electron@latest" code. In package.json wrote that

```
"electron": "17.1.0"
```

But node_modules folder was not created again.

What is the problem?
Also in package-lock.json node_modules wrote de_modules as following code;

```
"de_modules/@electron/get": {
  "version": "1.13.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@electron/get/-/get-1.13.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-U5vkXDZ9DwXtkPqlB45tfYnnYBN8PePp1z/XDCupnSpdrxT8/ThCv9WCwPLf9oqiSGZTkH6dx2jDUPuoXpjkcA==",
  "extraneous": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "env-paths": "^2.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "got": "^9.6.0",
    "progress": "^2.0.3",
    "semver": "^6.2.0",
    "sumchecker": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

Comment: This question was asked before here: [Is this answer helps you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250849/npm-install-doesnt-create-node-modules-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
If windows user name has non-english character, this problem occur. Anyone who have this problem, change your windows user name with only english characters.