# AWS synthetic canaries error - Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node_modules/exports'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to create a CloudWatch Synthetics Canary in AWS using terraform, and I'm able to create it fine, but it instantly fails with this message:
`Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node_modules/exports'`

I'm new to Synthetics, Node.js and terraform, so it's a perfect storm, but I feel i'm missing some knowledge.  I read that the node.js file needs to be in a folder structure of
`my_canary_folder > nodejs > node_modules > my_nodejs_zipfile.zip` but when I created that as instructed , it was empty and didn't work, instead producing that error.

I presumed I had to install nodejs on my MacOS, so I ran `npm install` which created the package.json file but didn't create the `node_modules` folder.  I've tried a number of different combinations of `npm init, sudo npm init, sudo npm install` but I can't get the node_modules folder to create so the canary keeps failing.  I think I expected that installing **nodejs** would add some content to the `node_modules` folder, but nothing has happened

Does anyone know what I need to do here to get it to run here please?

Here is my main.tf snippet in case this is useful:

```
resource "aws_synthetics_canary" "portal_test" {
  name                 = "portal_load"
  artifact_s3_location = "${var.artifact_location}"
  execution_role_arn   = "${aws_iam_role.cloudwatch_synthetics_role.arn}"
  handler              = "exports.handler"
  runtime_version      = "syn-nodejs-puppeteer-3.6"
  zip_file             = "nodejs/node_modules/portal_load.zip"
  success_retention_period = 31
  start_canary         = true
}
```

I've followed a lot of the answers in this link, but nothing seems to work: [npm install doesn't create node_modules directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250849/npm-install-doesnt-create-node-modules-directory)

When I run `npm install node` in the application root directory, even with sudo, it creates the `package.json`, but not the node_modules folder.  I've seen talk of the `node_modules` relating to the dependencies section of the `package.json`, but I can't find anything that relates to what is required for AWS CloudWatch.  I've tried `npm i` as well, but the message coming back says that everything has installed ok, but yet still no `node_modules` folder

Comment: Ok, I've now managed to populate a `node_modules` folder by running `npm install express --save`.  It has created a number of packages but doesn't include `exports`.  I really feel like I'm missing the correct instructions here, i can't find what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running into the same problem. Looking at your zipfile, I notice the path to the zip is `nodejs/node_modules`.

Based on [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_WritingCanary_Nodejs.html#CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_package), I think the path to the canary script *within* the zipfile needs to include the path, not the path *to* the zipfile.

I don't actually have this working yet, but what I've managed to glean so far is that there's a generic canary lambda (hence the runtimes we can choose from). The canary scripts are then loaded as lambda layers. So, the zipfile contents needs to follow the same pattern as [node layers like this blog](https://dev.to/afrazkhan/how-to-setup-aws-lambda-layers-nodejs-182).

I will update back here if I figure out how to *actually* get this working.

---

Update: The missing piece is the handler. Full implementation below.

The handler needs to target the js file under `nodejs/node_modules/<FILE_NAME>` and the corresponding exported function (i.e., `<FILE_NAME>.handler`).

With the following canary script:

```js
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger')
const synthetics = require('Synthetics')

const synCfg = synthetics.getConfiguration()
synCfg.disableStepScreenshots()

const entryPoint = async () => {
    // TODO: Use synthetics.executeStep
    url = 'https://<TARGET_URL>';
    const page = await synthetics.getPage();
    log.info(`Navigating to ${url}`)
    const res = await page.goto(url);

    if (page.url().includes('<REDIRECT_URL>')) {
        log.info('Url redirected')
    } else {
        throw 'URL does not redirect'
    }
};

moudle.exports = {
    handler: async () => {
        return await entryPoint();
    }
};
```

This bash script deploys and updates the canary:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -eux

tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d .canaries.$$.XXXXXXX)
trap 'rm -r ${tmp_dir}; exit' SIGINT EXIT

for canary in ./canaries/*.js; do
    canary_name="$(basename "$canary" .js)"
    mkdir -p "$tmp_dir/$canary_name/nodejs/node_modules"
    cp "$canary" "${tmp_dir}/${canary_name}/nodejs/node_modules/${canary_name}.js" 
    pushd "$tmp_dir/$canary_name" || { echo 'Failed to cd into tmp directory.' >&2; exit 1; }
    zip -r "$canary_name.zip" 'nodejs'
    aws s3 cp "$canary_name.zip" "s3://$CANARY_BUCKET/canaries/${canary_name}.zip"
    aws synthetics update-canary --name "$canary_name" \
        --code "S3Bucket=$CANARY_BUCKET,S3Key=canaries/${canary_name}.zip,Handler=${canary_name}.handler"
    popd || { echo 'Failed to popd' >&2; exit 1; }
done
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I had actually tried that and got the same error, but I eventually got it working by creating the folder path within the zip file and then made the terraform entry: ```zip_file = "portal_load.zip"```.  It turned out my script also didn't work - I'd tried to just use the record screen function and use that script in full, but the upload didn't like that.  I had to edit the standard blueprint file from the example in the docs and then paste a section of my recorded script within that.  Very convoluted, but I got there in the end.  Hope AWS changes it soon