# "npm install" not doing anything despite there being a package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm not sure if it was because of upgrading npm or node, but "npm install" was working all along up till the upgrade, and after struggling with this issue, decided to reverted back to using NodeJs v4.2.6 and npm v2.14.18 - still though, this hasn't resolved the issue. When removing my node_modules folder and then running "npm install", it does nothing as can be seen below:

[image]

This is my package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@^1.4.7",
      "angular-animate": "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@^1.4.8",
      "angular-bootstrap-contextmenu": "npm:angular-bootstrap-contextmenu@^0.9.6",
      "angular-loading-bar": "github:chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar@^0.8.0",
      "angular-local-storage": "npm:angular-local-storage@^0.2.2",
      "angular-messages": "github:angular/bower-angular-messages@^1.4.7",
      "angular-mocks": "github:angular/bower-angular-mocks@^1.4.7",
      "angular-ui-bootstrap": "npm:angular-ui-bootstrap@^0.14.0",
      "angular-ui-grid": "github:angular-ui/bower-ui-grid@^3.0.7",
      "angular-ui-router": "github:angular-ui/ui-router@^0.2.15",
      "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@^3.3.6",
      "bootstrap-sass": "github:twbs/bootstrap-sass@^3.3.6",
      "clean-css": "npm:clean-css@^3.4.9",
      "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@^4.5.0",
      "jquery": "github:components/jquery@2.1.3",
      "json": "github:systemjs/plugin-json@^0.1.0",
      "lodash": "npm:lodash@^3.10.1",
      "moment": "github:moment/moment@^2.10.6",
      "ngstorage": "npm:ngstorage@^0.3.9",
      "restangular": "github:mgonto/restangular@^1.5.1",
      "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@^0.0.2",
      "toastr": "github:CodeSeven/toastr@^2.1.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "npm:babel-core@^5.8.24",
      "babel-runtime": "npm:babel-runtime@^5.8.24",
      "core-js": "npm:core-js@^1.1.4"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.8.35",
    "babel-core": "^5.8.35",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-runtime": "^5.8.35",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "core-js": "^1.2.3",
    "del": "^2.1.0",
    "extend": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-cli": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-htmlhint": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp-karma": "0.0.5",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-preprocess": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-slash": "^1.1.3",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "isparta": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-async-sugar": "^1.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.0.1",
    "jspm": "^0.16.24",
    "karma": "^0.13.14",
    "karma-babel-preprocessor": "^5.2.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.2",
    "karma-coveralls": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.6",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-jspm": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-vs-reporter": "^0.8.0",
    "karma-xml-reporter": "^0.1.4",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.1",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.14.11",
    "ui-grid": "0.0.0",
    "yargs": "^3.29.0"
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I've cleared my npm cache, but that hasn't helped.

Comment: I highly recommend nvm for resolving issues with node and npm versioning: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Does npm correctly install other modules that you have created?  Can you make a backup of your `package.json` and then create a new one through `npm init` then try adding a new dependency with `npm i jslint --save` and seeing if that works.  It doesn't have to be `jslint`.  I just want to know what happens if you try any other package.

Comment: can you also try with 'npm install --loglevel=verbose' and if still nothing try --loglevel=silly

Comment: Thanks for the nvm tip - I've installed and will come in handy.
Regarding zero298 comment, it works find when I do that...and led me to realize that I've been using --save-dev all along, which I still seem to think is correct, but it adds dependencies to the devDependencies list in the package.json file, whereas --save adds to the dependencies. I realised that if I ran npm install --only=dev, it then installed all my devDependencies...I'm a little confused as this was working initially before I attempted the upgrade...could you shed some light on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm install hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs)