# Can't install anything using "npm install"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I updated my node.js installation since it was very outdated but now I'm stuck with `npm install` not working.
It starts doing it's thing but aborts about 30% into the installation on any package I've tried.
I have no more ideas on what to do since I tried reinstalling node and updating hit with no success.

Here's an output of `npm install --verbose` - https://gist.github.com/friiks/ad4fd4f02e8cc60740c369c45524343d

and here's the `package.json` I'm using

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "<git url>"
  },
  "author": "Pankucins",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "<git url>/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "<git url>#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "socket.io-p2p": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

*edit*

`npm install express --save` doesn't work as well, in any folder I've tried.

*edit #2*

Ok, I'm pretty sure it's git that causes the problem. 
I'm using cmder to do my console stuff in and this is what I see before npm stops.
First - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahzn5.png
Then - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGKgs.png
And after that it crashes.
FYI this is how the console looks after the crash when I don't redirect the output to a file - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXfTs.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried deleting the node_modules folder and doing npm cache clean ?

Comment: I removed node_modules folder before and did `npm cache clean` now but still no luck.

Comment: Check the upgrading on windows and reinstall sections on this site and try those out https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Sadly this did not help as well.

Comment: Have you looked into proxy issues? I had a similar issue and npm config set strict-ssl false worked for me

Comment: Tried that already with no success.

Comment: Is this your computer, or a virtual machine?

Comment: It's my local computer. It was running fine until I updated node and git.

Comment: Try `npm cache verify` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39376187/5576333)  solved the issue for me. I had set my npm to target somewhere else than http://registry.npmjs.org/.

Hope this helps to others!