# i can't install any node packages with npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I try to install node packeges with nmp. When i run, it says:

```
up to date, audited 356 packages in 7s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I see it as a dependency in my package-json like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "nodemon": "*"
  }
```

but there is no node_modules was installed..

Hope someone can help.

edit: I tried the commands given in the answers but it didn't work. still same

[ss from editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l49dv.png)

Comment: Have you looked [at any of these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401606/npm-doesnt-install-module-dependencies)?

Comment: Can you run `ls -la` in the root of the project and add the output to your question?

Comment: Don't add dependencies manually. Remove that `dependecies` section from your `package.json`, save and close the file, then run `npm i -s express nodemon` in your project directory. This will install the latest versions of both, with semver syntax to make sure you don't automatically install the next major version (should one come out) because major versions break backward compatibility and you never want those to get blindly installed. And if the regular way to install packages still doesn't work, please update your post accordingly.

Comment: Please check your answers available, try them, and see if they helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These commands solve the same problem and have a look at the attached links.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17282

[Can't install anything using "npm install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955755/cant-install-anything-using-npm-install)

```
npm install -g npm
npm cache clean
npm update
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few fixes to this issue.

---

The first one is to install the dependencies manually, as so.

```
$ npm install -s express nodemon
```

The command should install `express` and `nodemon` at the latest versions.

---

The second option is to run a few commands, as so (in the order given).

```
$ npm install -g npm
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm update
$ npm install
```

Basically, these are what the commands do (from 1-4).

1. This installs *npm* from *npm* (sounds weird, but there is an [*npm* package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm)).
2. This command forcefully cleans out the cache of npm.
3. As you can tell, `npm update` updates npm!
4. Finally, this command should be run in a directory where there is a `package.json` file. This installs all the dependencies listed in `package.json`.

---

<sub>Don't type out the $ in the terminal examples!</sub>