# npm not working even after setting all proxy config

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, proxy, http-proxy

System Info

```
RELEASE=19
CODENAME=tara
EDITION="Cinnamon"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 19 Tara"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tara_cinnamon_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_tara_cinnamon.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=help:linuxmint
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon

$which node
/usr/bin/node

$node -v
v8.10.0

$which npm
/usr/bin/npm

$npm -v
3.5.2

$cat ~/.npmrc
registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
proxy=http://usr:pwd@172.16.0.11:3128
strict-ssl=false

https-proxy=https://usr:pwd@172.16.0.11:3128
```

## I have given my username and password accordingly

```
$sudo npm install -g ember-cli
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli/-/broccoli-2.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-debug/-/broccoli-debug-0.6.5.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-funnel-reducer/-/broccoli-funnel-reducer-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-config-replace/-/broccoli-config-replace-1.1.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/broccoli-funnel/-/broccoli-funnel-2.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/configstore/-/configstore-4.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/dag-map/-/dag-map-2.0.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
npm ERR! fetch failed http://registry.npmjs.org/console-ui/-/console-ui-2.2.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 403
```

I have installed both npm and nodejs using apt install
I have tried everything, I am not getting any scratch her.
I keep getting the same error.
I am sure about my network setting, apt works fine with the proxy setting too

## What can be the fix?

Comment: did you try installing any other module? some other options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional/46677097#46677097

Comment: Yes i tried same kind of error