# Unable to use npm in any docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm trying to install the `artillery` NPM package using `npm` in a docker container with `npm install -g artillery`. However it hangs with this message

```
[..................] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 005fda8725330544
```

Initially I tried using the debian:stretch docker image, installing `nodejs` and `npm` with `apt`. I've also tried the  offical `node` docker image and the `alpine` image (with `apk add nodejs npm`. All of them have this same error.

I have working network in the containers and I can see the NPM registry fine in all the different docker containers

```
# curl http://registry.npmjs.org/
{"db_name":"registry","doc_count":1114477,"doc_del_count":341,"update_seq":16317727,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":13471206003,"data_size":11114653800,"instance_start_time":"1547073780489012","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":16317727}
```

Most people with this error have proxy issues, but I don't have any proxies set, nor have tried to set any I've left the config at default:

```
# npm config list
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v8.15.0 linux x64"

; node bin location = /usr/bin/node
; cwd = /
; HOME = /root
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

The most bizarre thing is if I instead create an Ubuntu VM (**not** container), install `node` and `npm` with `apt`, node works just fine! It seems like it's a docker problem.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions provided in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional ?

Comment: Yep, I've already found that and tried all the suggestions. Hence I think it's a docker problem as all works as expected in a VM.

Comment: And it's not just the artillery package either, `npm install -g npm` also hangs on the same error.