# Customize Theme in Ant Design Mobile React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, less, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to customize theme in [Ant Design Mobile React-Native](https://rn.mobile.ant.design/docs/react/introduce).  I'm using Expo-cli.

I tried to fork https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile-rn

and customized the theme variables in https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile-rn/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.tsx,

but when i install the forked repo and use `import {Button} from '@ant-design/react-native/lib/button'`, it result to error "Unable to resolve @ant-design/react-native/lib".

Then I rename the folder "components" to "lib" and remove the /lib in .gitignore file and reinstall the forked repo. It now works, but i'm not sure what i did is right. Please help me check if it is the correct way to use a forked repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the correct way to customize the theme which is by using the "[Provider](https://rn.mobile.ant.design/components/locale-provider/)".

```js
import {Provider} from '@ant-design/react-native';
import customTheme from './customTheme';

<Provider theme={customTheme}>
  <App />
</Provider>
```

customTheme.tsx file

```js
const brandPrimary = '#42b549';
const brandPrimaryTap = '#5CCF63';

export default {
  // 支付宝钱包默认主题
  // https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile/wiki/设计变量表及命名规范

  // 色彩, NOTE: must use `#000000` instead of `#000`
  // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/colors.html
  // 8-digit-hex to 4-digit hex https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/
  // https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5685348285808640 chrome will support `#RGBA`
  // 文字色
  color_text_base: '#000000',                  // 基本
  color_text_base_inverse: '#ffffff',          // 基本 _ 反色
  color_text_secondary: '#a4a9b0',          // 辅助色
  color_text_placeholder: '#bbbbbb',           // 文本框提示
  color_text_disabled: '#bbbbbb',              // 失效
  color_text_caption: '#888888',               // 辅助描述
  color_text_paragraph: '#333333',             // 段落
  color_link: brandPrimary,                 // 链接

  // 背景色
  fill_base: '#ffffff',                           // 组件默认背景
  fill_body: '#f5f5f9',                        // 页面背景
  fill_tap: '#dddddd',                            // 组件默认背景 _ 按下
  fill_disabled: '#dddddd',                       // 通用失效背景
  fill_mask: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)',              // 遮罩背景
  color_icon_base: '#cccccc',                     // 许多小图标的背景，比如一些小圆点，加减号
  fill_grey: '#f7f7f7',

  // 透明度
  opacity_disabled: '0.3',   // switch checkbox radio 等组件禁用的透明度

  // 全局/品牌色
  brand_primary: brandPrimary,
  brand_primary_tap: brandPrimaryTap,
  brand_success: '#6abf47',
  brand_warning: '#f4333c',
  brand_error: '#f4333c',
  brand_important: '#ff5b05',  // 用于小红点
  brand_wait: '#108ee9',

  // 边框色
  border_color_base: '#dddddd',

  // 字体尺寸
  // ---
  font_size_icontext: 10,
  font_size_caption_sm: 12,
  font_size_base: 14,
  font_size_subhead: 15,
  font_size_caption: 16,
  font_size_heading: 17,

  // 圆角
  // ---
  radius_xs: 2,
  radius_sm: 3,
  radius_md: 5,
  radius_lg: 7,

  // 边框尺寸
  // ---
  border_width_sm: 0.5,
  border_width_md: 1,
  border_width_lg: 2,

  // 间距
  // ---
  // 水平间距
  h_spacing_sm: 5,
  h_spacing_md: 8,
  h_spacing_lg: 15,

  // 垂直间距
  v_spacing_xs: 3,
  v_spacing_sm: 6,
  v_spacing_md: 9,
  v_spacing_lg: 15,
  v_spacing_xl: 21,

  // 高度
  // ---
  line_height_base: 1,           // 单行行高
  line_height_paragraph: 1.5,    // 多行行高

  // 图标尺寸
  // ---
  icon_size_xxs: 15,
  icon_size_xs: 18,
  icon_size_sm: 21,
  icon_size_md: 22,       // 导航条上的图标
  icon_size_lg: 36,

  // 动画缓动
  // ---
  ease_in_out_quint: 'cubic_bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1)',

  // 组件变量
  // ---

  actionsheet_item_height: 50,
  actionsheet_item_font_size: 18,

  // button
  button_height: 47,
  button_font_size: 18,

  button_height_sm: 23,
  button_font_size_sm: 12,

  primary_button_fill: brandPrimary,
  primary_button_fill_tap: brandPrimaryTap,

  ghost_button_color: brandPrimary,    // 同时应用于背景、文字颜色、边框色
  ghost_button_fill_tap: `${brandPrimary}99`, // alpha 60%  https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/XjbzAW

  warning_button_fill: '#e94f4f',
  warning_button_fill_tap: '#d24747',

  link_button_fill_tap: '#dddddd',
  link_button_font_size: 16,

  // modal
  modal_font_size_heading: 18,
  modal_button_font_size: 18, // 按钮字号
  modal_button_height: 50, // 按钮高度

  // list
  list_title_height: 30,
  list_item_height_sm: 35,
  list_item_height: 44,

  // input
  input_label_width: 17,       // InputItem、TextareaItem 文字长度基础值
  input_font_size: 17,
  input_color_icon: '#cccccc',
  input_color_icon_tap: brandPrimary,

  // tabs
  tabs_color: brandPrimary,
  tabs_height: 42,
  tabs_font_size_heading: 15,

  // segmented_control
  segmented_control_color: brandPrimary,  // 同时应用于背景、文字颜色、边框色
  segmented_control_height: 27,
  segmented_control_fill_tap: `${brandPrimary}10`,

  // tab_bar
  tab_bar_fill: '#ebeeef',
  tab_bar_height: 50,

  // toast
  toast_fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)',

  // search_bar
  search_bar_fill: '#efeff4',
  search_bar_height: 44,
  search_bar_input_height: 28,
  search_bar_font_size: 15,
  search_color_icon: '#bbbbbb', // input search icon 的背景色

  // notice_bar
  notice_bar_fill: '#fffada',
  notice_bar_height: 36,

  // switch
  switch_fill: '#4dd865',

  // tag
  tag_height: 25,
  tag_small_height: 15,

  // picker
  option_height: 42,            // picker 标题的高度

  toast_zindex: 1999,
  action_sheet_zindex: 1000,
  popup_zindex: 999,
  modal_zindex: 999,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The steps to do what I suggested in my above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603998/customize-ant-design-theme-in-react-native/58668452?noredirect=1#comment103641135_58668452) are:

1. Make sure you have a Github account and you are logged in.
2. Go to the repo that you wish to fork and click the fork button (see image)

[image: image of forking]

3. Once the repo has been forked to your Github account you can now make what ever changes that you want. You probably want to clone your copy of the repo to your computer to do this. Though it can be done on Github if the changes are minor.
4. Once the changes have been made on your repo you need to push those changes so that they are available on your repo.
5. Now that your changes are available on the repo, you can use them in your project.  To do that you need to remove the previous installation of the repo (if it was there) and then install your forked version.

You install it using the following format `npm install --save username/repo#branch-name`

I have used this method multiple times when repos that I require haven't been updated and have needed significant upgrades to get them working with new versions of RN.

I also usually look to make a pull request with my changes, especially if what I have done will benefit other users.

---

When testing you may wish to use your local copy of your repo rather than the one stored on Github. This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json), shows how to do that.

Basically in your dependencies section of your `package.json` add the path to your local copy of the repo with the appropriate name.

```
"dependencies": {
    "bar": "file:../foo/bar"
}
```

Comment: is it okay to use npm install --save "clipboard of repo link"?  "the one that says Clone with HTTPS"

Comment: i got error "rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 27e4144b87090cca" after running npm install --save "repo-link"

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue with your npm config. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional

Comment: unfortunately all the answers in the link do not solve the npm rollbackfailed issue :(

Comment: yarn add "repo-link" work for me, but it is not installing the source code from the forked repo to node_modules, which causes error "Unable to resolve @ant-design/react-native/lib". The lib folder is missing in node_module.

Comment: I rename the folder "components" to "lib" and removed the /lib in .gitignore file. It now works, but i'm not sure what i did is right. Please help me check if it is correct.

Comment: That doesn't sounds right to me. I forked their library and tried to install it into a clean Expo project, however it will not install. I think what they have on github and what they have on npm are different. Meaning that it would not be possible to just clone their repo and use it. I would reach out to the maintainers of the package at this point and see if they can help you.