# Not able to run the command 'npm install mqtt'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, virtual-machine, mqtt

When i run the above command, it shows the error :

> rollbackFailedOptional : verb npm-session 2b3ffdee576712c

What do i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

just tried it 10 mins ago and its fine, is it all package or that specific package ?

and oh maybe you can check to this [rollbackfailedoptional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional)

Comment: All the packages not just mqtt, because of this i'm not able to connect monogodb