# npm install error: rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session a0d68 for command npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

When I try to install babel I keep getting this error:

`rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session a0d68`

Node version is 12.16.1

npm version is 6.13.4

I just want to install babel and explore how it works. How do I do that?

[npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R32D.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

This is no Error. Just wait until the progress bar on the left grows. Also make sure your Terminal is focused while installing. if an Error occurs, it would be printed out red and the progress bar would disappear.

Comment: great thanks. i was connecting to my machine using putty terminal, it didn't work. After logging in directly in the machine and opening a native terminal it worked.