# npm install stuck at rollbackFailedOptional

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-modules

**node --version: 12.18.3


npm --version: 6.14.6


installed using nvm


OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3**

Whenever i'm running npm install  --save, it is stuck forever at rollBackFailedOption: verb npm-session xxxxxxx

My **proxy and https-proxy are both set to null**, as i dont have a company proxy...

I have **tried setting the registry to http from https**, but in vain.

Using the -**verbose option produces no errors.**

**Very occasionally**, it comes out of rollBackFailedOptional after a pretty long time, only to get **stuck at extract**.

Has anyone faced similar issues and/or successfully fixed them?

Comment: please check this [thread][1] hopefully you will see an reply that will help unblock you. #cheers


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional

Comment: @ishan did you try the thread shared by victor?

Comment: @globefire yes i tried changing the registry and removing all proxies but it hasn't worked