# rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 9a5b1fb467359b45

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am beginner in React.js and I am trying to Install `react` through `npm` BUT i am stuck on an Error.

**The Problem**

When i try to install `npm install react` then node server is stuck on `[..................] - rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 9a5b1fb467359b45`  .

When i type this :-

```
    > npm config rm proxy
    > npm config rm https-proxy
```

nothing happens in Terminal

**What have i tried ?**

1). I have also tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional). BUT this didn't work for me.

**EDIT**

After some time it is showing `fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule react@17.0.1 checking installable status`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Please provide the full verbatim error message. Are you behind a firewall or proxy?

Comment: Now it is showing `fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule react@17.0.1 checking installable status  `. AND there is no other message

Comment: @Progam So you did the third (important) line `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`, too, right? Could you please `ping registry.npmjs.org` and tell us the outcome?

Comment: @Progam if you are using windows you might try your npm commands in administrator terminal, have you tried clearing your npm cache ?

Comment: @shubhamjha, When i reinstall the node and tried again THEN it worked. I think the problem was in running program.

Comment: @SimplyComple0x78, When i reinstall the node and tried again THEN it worked. I think the problem was in running program.

Comment: Well, sad to hear, that your node has been broken in some unknown way. Reinstalling is always a last resort - but glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i reinstall the node and tried again THEN it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments (for future visitors), you should try to run `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`. If that doesn't work, try to `ping registry.npmjs.org`. If the ping works, you should try to reinstall Node.

Comment: When i reinstall the node and tried again THEN it worked. I think the problem was in running program