# npx react-native init hangs without any output

Tags: react-native, npm, npx

I want to create a new `react-native` project using this command in the terminal of visual studio :

`npx react-native init project-name`

But the terminal freezes for 10 minutes in this line

`⸨⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠇ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session e582ffa365b35dcf`

#### Screenshot

[image]

I've tried these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional) but none of them worked for me.

When I tried `npx create-react-app teachat`, it worked very well. I got confused if the problem is related to `npm` or `react-native`.

Answer (score 0):

For these reasons it could occure.

1.network connectivity: some times your internet connection is okay but some applications may interfere when downloading dependency. In this case, try using a different network.

2. Try removing react-native-cli from global installation with this `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`

3.Try different version or typescript template
`npx react-native init projectname --version X.XX.X` or `npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript`

Answer (score 0):

The react native cli is a deprecated method of creating react native projects,the init method is the one currently in use. Check under `Creating a new application` the [official docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Uninstall `react-native-cli` and use the same command as you did `npx react-native init projectname`