# Failed to install appium using node Js

Tags: node.js, npm, appium, npm-install

I want to install appium using node.js on Windows 10, I installed the node js correctly but when it comes to installing appium I'm getting a failure.
The command used :

```
npm install -g appium
```

The failure :

```
[...............] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session
```

I tried the steps illustrated in this issue [npm install Error: rollbackFailedOptional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional) but it still not working :

```
    # first this
> npm config rm proxy
> npm config rm https-proxy

# then this
> npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```