# npm install hangs as well as npm install --verbose

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I started with a simple Ionic application that I cloned from git.
After doing so I tried installing npm but it froze at "loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree", so after some searching I found this solution: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17228 
Basically saying that if I remove package-lock.json it'll work.

Which it did but then froze at: `range manifest for copy-descriptor@^0.1.0`

And after a bit of searching I found this: [npm install hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs/30373440)

Basically saying that I should use `npm install --verbose` to see what's going on.

Unfortunately it got stuck at: 
`fetchMetadata: info lifecycle cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.4.3-dev~postpack: cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.4.3-dev`

And I am an amateur in this but I'm trying to learn. 
Can somebody explain why this is occurring? 
I checked my internet connection but it's fine, and my npm version is recent. What could this mean and how to solve it?

Details:
npm version 6.4.1

```
"@angular/cli": "^6.0.0",
"@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2",
"@types/lodash": "4.14.70",
"@types/node": "^10.5.0",
"@types/underscore": "1.8.1",
"ionic": "3.20.0",
"typescript": "2.3.4"
```

Comment: I know it's not exactly an answer, but I'd recommend just trying Yarn (https://yarnpkg.com/en/) instead of npm. :)

Comment: how you solved this issue?i am facing the same