# npm install stuck on "checking installable status"?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have recently updated a project where the last udpate was about a month ago, but failed to deploy to the server. After some investigation, it is because it is stuck in `npm install`, or more precisely, stuck at a line saying
[image]
This sutck happens on different package when trying on different machine, so it seems to be related to npm instead of any package.

I have made no changes to the `package.json`, only on some other javascript files. Also, the last deploy was about a month ago. In other words, the `npm install` can be run without problem last month.

This problem can be replicated by copying the `package.json` file to an empty folder and run `npm install`. The `package.json` file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-14",
        "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "eventemitter3": "https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter3/-/eventemitter3-1.2.0.tgz"
    }
}
```

I am using node 11.15.0, npm 6.7.0 through nvm. As it is a running project on live, upgrading or downgrading node and npm version is not an option without some careful planning, and seems to be an overkill at the moment.

For reference, I noticed that there is [an outage in npmjs registory recently](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/8cgldky16yk4), but it seems to be fixed, so I am not sure if it is related. Have anyone had similar problem recently? Or any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: do you get any more info if you use: "npm install ionic --loglevel verbose" to see if it gives a more detailed picture? I ran your JSON locally and it didn't get stuck but it did fail in the sass compile but that I suspect is my version of python not been compatible for sasss, might be worth checking out this too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs

Comment: I get a ton of GCC compilation errors also in the sass stages - but no hang.