# Can't install nestjs-cli v9

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I tried to run `npm i -g @nestjs/cli`

The installation hang on `reify:rxjs: timing`

```
reifyNode:node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics-cli/node_modules/rxjs
```

I tried with `node v16 v14 npm 8.18`.

I tried increase npm timeout, clear cache, remove proxy but nothing is working.

Comment: it went fine here

Comment: Now it hang on reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/rxjs Completed in 1070ms
I removed nvm and installed v16.17.0. How can i find the cause for this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/