# Unable to run any commands in npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Any command I run in npm (v9.5.1) gets stuck. This includes both installing packages and creating vite projects. I am using ubuntu 22.10. When I try `npm create vite@latest --verbose` I get the following:

```
npm verb cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@9.5.1
npm info using node@v18.16.0
npm verb title npm create vite@latest
npm verb argv "create" "vite@latest" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/firesquid/.npm/_logs/2023-04-20T02_36_19_073Z-
npm verb logfile /home/firesquid/.npm/_logs/2023-04-20T02_36_19_073Z-debug-0.log
```

My cursor then sits idly for all eternity below the last line

When I try to install packages for a cloned project with `npm install --verbose`, I get the following:

```
npm verb cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
npm info using npm@9.5.1
npm info using node@v18.16.0
npm verb title npm install
npm verb argv "install" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verb logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/firesquid/.npm/_logs/2023-04-20T02_39_20_708Z-
npm verb logfile /home/firesquid/.npm/_logs/2023-04-20T02_39_20_708Z-debug-0.log
```

My cursor then continues to sit at the bottom waiting for an entire minute does nothing.

I have tried the following fixes:

- Restarting my computer
- Reinstalling nvm
- Installing node from the website rather than nvm
- `npm cache clear --force`
- Making sure I have the correct
- Everything on this other question: [npm install hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs)

EDIT: I am not using a vpn. This problem exists only on my desktop, since my laptop works fine when connected to the same network. It appears to be just not doing the get request to the npm registry.

Comment: Have you tried it without using `--verbose`?

Comment: Without verbose it outputs nothing and just has my cursor blinking on the next line.

Answer (score -1):

Schrodinger's IT comes to save me. I came back to my computer today and it works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).