Why my terminal got stuck when I try to install ElectronJS from npm
I tried to install electron.js following a decent tutorial. But somehow, I couldn't install the library at all. It's just stuck on the last line for hours. Here are my terminal activities:
PS E:\study\ElectronJS\image_resizer> npm i electron
npm WARN deprecated phin@2.9.3: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[##################] \ reify:core-js: WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature 


Sorry to hear you've run into trouble, that sounds frustrating. I think those logs are a misdirection, just warnings and shouldn't cause the process to hang. It would be helpful if you could provide a bit more details about your environment (OS, Node version, npm version etc). You might also want to have a look at this thread which deals with a similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs

my OS = windows 11, Node version = v22.0.0, NPM version = 10.1.0. I  looked to the other issue but I found No Solutions..

Great thanks - my next step would be to run npm install --verbose to see if that gives more info on where in the stack we're getting stuck

I tried to uninstall node and restart my computer and reinstalled nodejs. my problem not fixed but i got a diffrent error message =>
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
